# Is there an way to avoid writing constructors for all the types in a std::variant class member?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, variant

I have a `struct` such as this:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    std::variant<int, float, char> b;

    A() = default;
};
```

I want to add a constructor which will initialize both `a` and `b`. It seems I will have to write a constructor for all the types in `b` like `A::A(int a1, int b1)`, `A::A(int a1, float b1)` etc.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried to set second one of constructor's arguments to the type `std::variant<int, float, char>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a templated constructor for you class, and, at best, apply perfect forwarding to pass its argument to the constructor of `variant` member:

```
template <typename T>
A::A(int i, T&& t) : a(i), b(std::forward<T>(t)) { }
```

Then, you can write, e.g.:

```
A obj1(1, -7.4f);  // float variant member
A obj2(2, 7);      // int variant member
A obj3(3, 'c');    // char variant member
```

No unnecessary moves/copies/temporaries will be involved.

Answer (score 2):

I guess something like this will also do the work, however, it will copy the variant that you pass.

`A::A(int a1, std::variant<int, float, char> b1)`

The ability to pass only required type may be an advantage. However, I would not recommend using this over another answer's solution.